# Return json object from executed function in presenter method

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I need load json object from anonymous function to variable *instance*.

In this example is instance undefined.

I am sure, the solution is simple, but newbie in node and no answer found...:(

```
module.exports = {
    create: function(req,res){
        instance = EngineInstance.findById(req.body.engineInstanceId).exec(function(err,instance){
            if (err) return res.send(err,500);
            if (!instance) return res.send("No engine instance found!", 404);
            return instance;
        });
        namespamce = instance.namespace;...
    }
};
```

Comment: why do you have two variables with same name `instance`?

Comment: instance defined in exec is not available in method create. I am trying get out variable to the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a very common and fundamental misconception about how asynchronous code works. Full stop. Go read tutorials and do guided exercises. Asynchronous IO such as `findById` you have above uses CALLBACKS that invoke functions with result variables. It does not use RETURN VALUES because they are useless due to the order in which asynchronous code executes.

```
module.exports = {
    create: function(req,res){
        instance = EngineInstance.findById(req.body.engineInstanceId).exec(function(err,instance){
            if (err) return res.send(err,500);
            if (!instance) return res.send("No engine instance found!", 404);
            //it is useless to return a value from this anonymous async callback
            //nothing will receive it. It will be ignored.
            //probably something like this is what you need
            req.namespamce = instance.namespace;
        });
        //do NOT put code here that needs req.namespace. This code runs BEFORE
        //the `findById` I/O callback runs.
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I am starting with async javascript and sometimes it is hard to go over know-how of standard synchronous programming.

Comment: Yes, don't feel bad about it. Everyone has a struggle to adjust to this. Asynchronous is just so fundamentally different from synchronous code. It takes a while before the light bulb finally lights up.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the MYSQL query to query multiple things together instead of isolating the query for accessPoint and the added this code:

```
results[0].accessPoint = JSON.parse(results[0].accessPoint)
res.send(results[0]);
```

Now I get this back and its exactly what I wanted:

```
"accessPoint": {
    "mode": "client",
    "rate": 0,
    "ssid": "RMG",
    "signal": 0,
    "channel": 0,
    "password": "",
    "username": "example@aol.com"
  }
```